# Does Elasticsearch Nest support Update By Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to use the UpdateByQuery method on the high level client but can't find any documentation for Nest. They have great documentation if I wanted to make a CURL request but nothing for NEST. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html
If anyone has and example of them using it or can share documentation they have found that would be awesome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) is supported in NEST. Here's an example [adapted from the integration tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Document/Multiple/UpdateByQuery/UpdateByQueryApiTests.cs). [NEST Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html) for Index and Update APIs is planned :)

```
private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<Test>(m => m
            .IndexName("tests")
            .TypeName("test")
        );

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    var index = IndexName.From<Test>();

    if (client.IndexExists(index).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(index);

    client.CreateIndex(index, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Test>(map => map
                .Properties(props => props
                    .Text(s => s.Name(p => p.Text))
                    .Keyword(s => s.Name(p => p.Flag))
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(new[] {
            new Test { Text = "words words", Flag = "bar" },
            new Test { Text = "words words", Flag = "foo" }
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    client.Count<Test>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Match(m => m
                .Field(p => p.Flag)
                .Query("foo")
            )
        )
    );

    client.UpdateByQuery<Test>(u => u
        .Query(q => q
            .Term(f => f.Flag, "bar")
        )
        .Script("ctx._source.flag = 'foo'")
        .Conflicts(Conflicts.Proceed)
        .Refresh(true)
    );

    client.Count<Test>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Match(m => m
                .Field(p => p.Flag)
                .Query("foo")
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Test
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Observe that the count from the first Count API call is 1, and on the second Count API call after the Update By Query API call, it's 2.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere for the following two: 1. How to update multiple fields? 2. How to update the whole object/document? BTW the link you provided has changed: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Tests/Document/Multiple/UpdateByQuery/UpdateByQueryApiTests.cs

Comment: For example: 1. Is it possible to update two fields with one call or do I have to call `UpdateByQuery` for each field? 2. Is it possible to update all fields with one call without specifying all the fields (to just input an object into some method to update the document)?

Comment: You can update two fields with scripting `"ctx._source.flag = 'foo'; ctx._source.flag2 = 'bar';"`. You may be able to get creative with scripting to be able to pass an object as a param to a script, and iterate over its properties to update properties of the document. There is no method to pass a document as there is on `Update<TDocument, TPartialDocument>`. I think the original intent was that a user would likely want to use property values of each document to update them.